# How to partially fit a piecewise polynomial with segment boundaries unknown?

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, curve-fitting, splines, polynomial

Suppose that I have the some data like this.

```
f=function(x) { (x<0) *2500+ (x-50)^2*(x>=0 & x<100)+(x>=100 & x<=150)*(2500-(x-100)*20)+(x>150)*1500 }
plot(x, f(x)+200*rnorm(length(x)))
```

[image]

I want to find out piecewise polynomial fits in a subset (the subset could be the whole set, but it doesn't have to be) of a dataset. In this example, the resulted region would be 0 to 100 (2nd order convex, known beforehand), and 100 to 150 (1st order downward, known beforehand). The data points to the left of 0 and the right of 150 are "don't care". The height of the left end and the right end (at 0 and 100 in this example) of the first region must be the same. The segment boundaries (e.g., 0, 100, 150) are unknown before fitting.

I see some examples to fit a piecewise function.

https://bookdown.org/tpinto_home/Beyond-Linearity/piecewise-regression-and-splines.html

```
pred7 <- predict(lm(triceps~ age + I((age-5)*(age>=5)) +
                                   I((age-10)*(age >= 10)) +
                                   I((age-20)*(age >= 20)) +
                                   I((age-30)*(age >= 30)) +
                                  I((age-40)*(age >= 40)),
                    data = triceps))
```

But this method requires the boundaries are known. Could anybody let me know how to fit a given piece-wise polynomial function (without knowing the boundary of each piece, but the orders of polynomial and some constraints mentioned above are known) only in a subset of all the data?

Note, in this example, there is only one such piecewise polynomial of 2nd and 1st order. But one can easily imagine the data may have many piecewise polynomials in different regions (for example, one can repeat the test data along the x-axis). The method should be able to detect muliple piecewise polynomials given a data set.

```
# the repeated data
x1 =c(x, x-x[1]+x[length(x)]+1)
y1 =c(y, y)
```

Comment: It looks like splines could work for you.

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: OK.  They seem awfully similar to me.  This one is answerable; if I really needed to do this I would write some kind of moderately stupid/brute-force method for searching over possible breakpoints.  The `segmented` package can do piecewise polynomial fits with unknown breakpoints, but not with heterogeneous orders ...

Comment: @BenBolker You clearly missed the constrains that I mentioned in the question.

Comment: I didn't miss them.  That would be an extra challenge.  What I'm saying is that I can see how to set this up in principle, but it would be a lot of work. I hope for your sake that someone has already implemented a sufficiently general machine to do this. (Since I'm not going to be able to solve this, I'm trying to give suggestions about starting points that might be useful.)